# Is there a command-line switch to run all the targets in an MS Build file?

Tags: msbuild

Is there a short-hand like so:

```
> msbuild.exe MyBuildFile.xml /t:*
```

To run all the targets in `MyBuildFile.xml` in the order in which they appear in the build file? Or do I have to write a semi-colon separated list of all the target names on the command line or in the RSP file?

Of course, the * doesn't work and that's why I am asking.

I am running MS Build version 15.1.

Comment: Not 100% sure but AFAIK when MsBuild evaluates a file (and all it's imported files) it doesn't keep track of which Target was specified in which file. As such, it is impossible to figure out 'all targets in MyBuildFile.xml' because they cannot be distinguished from 'all targets' (there's hundreds of targets in a standard project btw). So yeah, specify them manually on the commandline, or manually add a master target in the file which depends on all targets you want built (LeY's answer), or automatic: grep the file as text or xml to find your targets then pass to msbuild on the commandline.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "All" target in your MyBuildFile.xml , then you can do.

```
> msbuild.exe MyBuildFile.xml /t:All
```

Sample from Default Build Target

```
  <!--
    ============================================================
                                        Build

    The main build entry point.
    ============================================================
    -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BuildDependsOn>
      BeforeBuild;
      CoreBuild;
      AfterBuild
    </BuildDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target
      Name="Build"
      Condition=" '$(_InvalidConfigurationWarning)' != 'true' "
      DependsOnTargets="$(BuildDependsOn)"
      Returns="$(TargetPath)" />
```